# To download a file when created in php

Tags: php, download

I have created a file in php like the code below

```
    $my_file = WP_OPTIONS_REPLACE.'/my_options.sql';
    $handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Please give write permission to the folder.  '.$my_file);
```

After that i write some contain in that file. like

```
    fwrite($handle, $sql);
```

How can i download the file automatically ? please help me.

Comment: See the answer here: [Renaming files when downloading it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1801076)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to do something like this:

```
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=document.pdf');
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('document.pdf'));
readfile('document.pdf');
```

First we are outputting headers to tell the browser to expect a file download attachment, and the type of file etc.
then we output the actual file data to the browser.