# Is it possible to convert byte array/stream to files such as Word,Excel, PDF in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wcf

I have a query regarding file operations using JavaScript-

Scenario - My JS function calls a wcf service which returns the file content in the form of byte array or stream and the mime type. This byte array/stream needs to be converted to a file and which will be downloaded on  user's machine.
**[Reference code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27946228/file-download-a-byte-array-as-a-file-in-javascript-extjs)** -

```
var arr = "This is test content";
var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arr);
var a = window.document.createElement('a');

a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([byteArray], {
    type: 'text/plain'
}));
a.download = "Test";

document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();

document.body.removeChild(a);
```

The code works for only text files. Files with mime type other than text are corrupted.
I understand that file operations are severly restricted at client side, but just to confirm - Is there anyway to convert byte array/stream to files such as Word,Excel, PDF and etc ?

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27946228/file-download-a-byte-array-as-a-file-in-javascript-extjs

Comment: @Akhoy Thanks. Same URL as the reference code. As i said, text files are working but not word or pdf.

Comment: How to do this on .NET C#? I need to convert a File MIMEType octet-stream (format bytestream) to a excel is it possible too?

Answer (score 2):

I accomplish a similar goal with this.  Pick up from where you have your byteArray, and try this:

```
    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
    var a = window.document.createElement('a');   
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([byteArray], { type:'application/octet-stream' }));

    // supply your own fileName here...
    a.download = "YourFileName.XLSX";

    document.body.appendChild(a)
    a.click();
    document.body.removeChild(a)
```

Setting contentType to "application/octet-stream" will accommodate any binary file type.

Comment: This seems dangerous, btw.  Basically, you could **force** a file to download to a remote computer, even if it only lands in their browser downloads folder.  You are creating a download link, then clicking on it.  I wonder why this isn't stopped by modern browsers?