# How to download any file from Byte Array in Cordova application?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have a cordova - ionic application.
I want to download a file from webservice and the file may be any type(JPG,PDG,DOCX etc). I cannot download the file from direct URL. So the app is taking byte array of the file from Webservice.

Anybody know how to download the file in Mobile from the Byte Array. Please help me.

Comment: From webservice what you get? image path?

Comment: No. IN webservice I am converting the file to byte array string. Then sending the string to mobile app. In mobile app i want to save(download) the file.

Comment: Instead of convert file to byte array, you can download file from url only

Comment: Try fileTransfer plugin http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/

Comment: Dear friend. I cannot do that due to the client's requirement. Thats why I clearly mentioned in my question like this 'I cannot download the file from direct URL'. I already know how to download from the URL.

Comment: ok sorry. this should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27946228/file-download-a-byte-array-as-a-file-in-javascript-extjs

Comment: thanks. but not working. its cordova-ionic app and ipad.

Comment: can you provide dummy url where i can get byte string so may be i can help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the 
cordova-plugin-file and the 
cordova-plugin-file-opener2 plugin.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file

https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener2

in function with the webservice your code should look like that:

```
var bytes = new Uint8Array(data.d);
app.writePDFToFile(fileName.split(fileName.split, bytes);
```

and here is teh function forcing the download:

```
writePDFToFile: function (fileName, data) {

try {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory, function (directoryEntry) {
        directoryEntry.getFile(fileName, { create: true }, function (fileEntry) {

            fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {
                fileWriter.onwriteend = function (e) {

                    //window.open(cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory + fileName, '_system', 'location=yes');

                    cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(cordova.file.externalApplicationStorageDirectory + fileName, 'application/pdf',
                        {
                            error: function (e) {
                                console.log('Error status: ' + e.status + ' - Error message: ' + e.message);
                            },
                            success: function () {
                                console.log('file opened successfully');
                            }
                        }
                    );
                };

                fileWriter.onerror = function (e) {
                    alert(e);
                };

                var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' });

                fileWriter.write(blob);

            }, function onerror(e) {
                alert(e);
            });
        }, function onerror(e) {

            alert(e);
        });
    }, function onerror(e) {            
        alert(e);
    });

} catch (e) {
     alert(e);
}
},
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: I tried this and can save the file now. But another Error when open the file using Acrobat reader app 'The document cannot be opened because it is not a valid pdf file'. Below the code:

In web service(C#):
string file_path=“…path to the pdf file..”;
string data_to_send_to_mobile=System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(File.ReadAllBytes(file_path));

In Mobile(Javascript) :
var str=data_to_send_to_mobile;
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
 data.push(str.charCodeAt(i));
}
var fileName=‘any_name.pdf’;
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL( ….

Comment: Solved it! I used base64string to take from webservice. Thanks deru.